# Where is Wildfly 9.0.2.Final BOM?

Tags: maven, wildfly, wildfly-9, maven-bom

This builds:

```
<dependencyManagement>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools</artifactId>
            <version>8.2.1.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**But it doesn't:**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Cannot find *org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate:9.0.2.Final*.

**Where can I find BOM for Wildfly 9.0.2.Final?**

Or if it doesn't exist, why if Wildfly 9 isn't so new? We have WildFly 10 already!

Answer (score 2):

There does not appear to be a version for 9.0.2.Final.

You should be able to use:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
   <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0-wildfly-with-hibernate3</artifactId>
   <version>9.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

without any problems though.

[The Central Repository Search Engine](http://search.maven.org) is your friend when trying to resolve these kinds of questions.